# Content tools gives save confirmation but does not save on php project

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system

### Objective

To make my website editable using [Content Tools](http://getcontenttools.com/)

### Background

I added Content Tools to my website [Package Mules](http://packagemules.com/). I have sections that can be edited by the public. Security is not a concern at this point, it is a very small site.

### Problem

It gives me a checkmark that it saved, unlike before where I would get an "X" meaning error. As you can see in [this screencast](http://screencast.com/t/WumwSISxZX). But when I refresh the page it seems that it did not actually save.

### Code

#### Repo

https://github.com/JGallardo/package-mules

### HTML (for index.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html lang="en">
<?php include 'includes/head.html';?>

<body>
    <?php include 'includes/nav.html';?>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Package Mules</h1>
                <p>Welcome to the future home of package mules. Our mission is to help bring movers together with low cost options for moving.</p>
                <p>We set up an editable page so we can get public feedback. Please be considerate and only post appropriate content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>The thing you hate most about moving is?</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div data-editable data-name="moving-1">
                    <blockquote>
                        [Enter content here]
                    </blockquote>
                    <p>[your name]</p>
                </div>
                <div data-editable data-name="moving-2">
                    <blockquote>
                        [Enter content here]
                    </blockquote>
                    <p>[your name]</p>
                </div>
                <div data-editable data-name="moving-3">
                    <blockquote>
                        [Enter content here]
                    </blockquote>
                    <p>[your name]</p>
                </div>
                <div data-editable data-name="moving-4">
                    <blockquote>
                        [Enter content here]
                    </blockquote>
                    <p>[your name]</p>
                </div>
                <div data-editable data-name="moving-5">
                    <blockquote>
                        [Enter content here]
                    </blockquote>
                    <p>[your name]</p>
                </div>
                <div data-editable data-name="moving-6">
                    <blockquote>
                        [Enter content here]
                    </blockquote>
                    <p>[your name]</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </seciton>

    <?php include 'includes/footer.html';?>
    <?php include 'includes/scripts.html';?>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var editor;

            ContentTools.StylePalette.add([
                new ContentTools.Style('Author', 'author', ['p'])
            ]);

            editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
            editor.init('*[data-editable]', 'data-name');

            editor.bind('save', function (regions) {
                var name, payload, xhr;

                // Set the editor as busy while we save our changes
                this.busy(true);

                // Collect the contents of each region into a FormData instance
                payload = new FormData();
                for (name in regions) {
                    if (regions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        payload.append(name, regions[name]);
                    }
            }

            // Send the update content to the server to be saved
            function onStateChange(ev) {
                // Check if the request is finished
                if (ev.target.readyState == 4) {
                    editor.busy(false);
                    if (ev.target.status == '200') {
                        // Save was successful, notify the user with a flash
                        new ContentTools.FlashUI('ok');
                    } else {
                        // Save failed, notify the user with a flash
                        new ContentTools.FlashUI('no');
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onStateChange);
            xhr.open('POST', '/index.php');
            xhr.send(payload);

            var_dump($_POST); 
        });
    });

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Would be great if you could share the PHP for saving files on your git hub channel.  I know you took the repo down, but would love to not have to write that code up :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is the `var_dump($_POST);` call in you're JavaScript. I'm not a PHP coder but I'm assuming that's a PHP call and that it should be within PHP tags.

The reasons this appears to work is that the `onStateChange` callback is called after this error. So the process of events looks a bit like this:

- You click the save button.
- The editor triggers the `save` event calling your save code.
- The editor is put in busy state by the save code.
- The save code binds a callback function to your `index.php` request and then sends it to the server.
- An error is raised due to the `var_dump($_POST);` statement. This error causes the execution of the code to stop and so never return to the editor which means the editor doesn't actually leave edit mode.
- The request sent succeeds and on a response from the server the callback registered earlier (`onStateChange`) is called.
- The `onStateChange` callback sets the editor to a non-busy state and fires the OK message because you got a 200 response from `index.php`.

This gives the illusion that everything went OK when actually an error occurred in your JavaScript. Checking the console you should see the error.